# vim configuration to turn on syntax for .conf files

Tags: vim

I have a config file under my python project, called "logging.conf", the file looks like:

```
[formatters]
keys: console, logging

[formatter_console]
format: %(asctime)s | %(message)s

[formatter_logging]
format: %(message)s

etc etc etc
```

Tried `:syntax on`, nothing happened, the .conf files look very plain. Is there anyway I can turn on some syntax to make the .conf file more colorful and readable?

Comment: Did you try it without the `/`? `:syntax on`

Comment: sorry, actually I did type :syntax on, had a typo there :) no, :syntax on doesn't help.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can check [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/) or the Internet for a suitable syntax.

As a first approximation, this somewhat looks like DOS / Windows *INI files*. Vim comes with a syntax for them; try

```
:setf dosini
```

If that suits you, you can add a filetype detection rule:

```
:autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile logging.conf setf dosini
```

See `:help ftdetect` for details.

Comment: got way with it by adding "au BufEnter,BufRead *.conf setf dosini" to my vimrc. Thanks!

Comment: alternatively, you could use `au BufEnter,BufRead *conf* setf dosini` to enable syntax highlight in conf, .conf, /config and .config files.

Answer (score 5):

Your file looks plain, it is correct. ( I assume that you have already set `conf` as the filetype of your current buffer  `:set ft?` to verify).

if you check your `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/conf.vim`

you will see, there are three different colors will be shown in a `conf` file:

- hi comment, lines starting with `#`
- hi string, text wrapped by `' or "`
- and normal text

your current text has no comment, no quoted text. so it shows just in one color.

The file you show (python conf) is actually ini structure. try Ingo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I almost have that kind of text style but mine was the ansible hosts file, I found a lot of options here [filetype.vim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/master/runtime/filetype.vim). I used `povini` or `texmf` for my `ansible hosts file` text highlights

To configure it in your `.vimrc`.

1. Grab the string before `setf`, so in case of `provini`, it is `au BufNewFile,BufRead .povrayrc`
2. Replace the last string(`.povrayrc`) with `*.conf`

The final config is `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.conf` for your `.vimrc`

Answer (score 0):

The key issue here is that the syntax in your conf file is usually associated with .ini files. Setting the type (ingo's answer) fixes this issue. Alternatively you could just rename your file.

`mv logging.conf logging.ini`

`echo "syntax on" >> ~/.vimrc`

Setting **.ini** as the file extension maybe more desirable than having custom rules. (I do understand that this may not be possible in all cases)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33435202)